# Mapping from a collection to an array

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi I looked and only saw examples from arrays to list\collection but not the other way around.

I have a collection with an attribute `AccIndex` that I want to map to an
array with an attribue named `AccIndex`.

I tried the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AccountCollection, AcctArray[]>().
    ForMember(d=> d.AccIndex, 
         o=>MapFrom(s => s.AcctList.Select(c => c.AccIndex).ToArray()));
```

**This gives me null**, and with the `toArray` I feel it will only make everything slower (toArray and than breaking it up again).

Isn't there a simple way to map between the two? The only difference is that one is a collection and the other array but somehow I find nothing on google.

Some more stuff I tried that always resulted with many nulls:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AccountCollection,
    AcctArray>();
Mapper.Map(AcctIndexesList, newIndexesArray);

Mapper.CreateMap<AccountCollection, 
    AcctArray[]>();
Mapper.Map(AcctIndexesList, newIndexesArray2);
```

I was asked to show how the collection and array look like so:

```
public class AccountCollection: IList, ICollection, IList<AcctIndexes>,     
 ICollection<AcctIndexes>, IEnumerable<AcctIndexes>, IEnumerable {

public AcctIndexesCollection();
public virtual int Count { get; }
public int Rows { get; set; }
public virtual AcctIndexes this[int index] { get; set; }
public virtual int Add(AcctIndexes value);
 ...
}

public class AcctIndexes : IFormattable
{
    public bool AccIndexSpecified;
    public AcctIndexes();

    public int AccIndex { get; set; }
}
```

And an array of these:

```
public partial class AcctArray {
  private int accIndexField;    
  public int AccIndex 
  {
     get {
           return this.accIndexField;
         }
     set {
           this.accIndexField = value;
         }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use a proper formatting.

Comment: The **System.LINQ** namespace contains an extension method `List<TSource> ToList(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` which is available to all implementation of *ICollection<TSource>* because it extends *IEnumerable<TSource>*. Does that help:

Comment: Show your `AccountCollection` and `AcctArray` classes.

Comment: I thought about it, but as far as I know "toList\toArray" are o(n), meaning it goes through all the list to make it a list\array, and after that it will go through the list\array again in order to actually do the mapping - 
so it will double the time. In that case I rather just make a for loop and map it myself - im trying to use the automapper to increase speed (:

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed my problem.
My problem was I didn't use the mapper correctly. 
On the "CreateMapper" U need to put only the core items, and on the "Mapper.Map" u need to put only the generic collection of them.
In my case:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AcctIndexes, AcctIndexes>();
Mapper.Map<ICollection<AcctIndexes>, AcctIndexes[]>();
```